# String LinkedList toString( ) Error

Tags: java, linked-list, tostring

so I'm building a class that is a string stored as a linked list. 
For some reason, whenever I try to print out a string I get a `NullPointerException`. This only happens when I try to print a string that I copied in the second constructor.

```
class Node
{
char c;
Node next;
int index;
}

public class StringLink {

int len;
Node head= new Node();
public StringLink(String init)
{
   head.index=0;
   Node temp= head;
   len=init.length();
   int i=0;
   while (i<this.len)
   {
     Node n= new Node();
     n.c=init.charAt(i);
     n.index=i+1;
     temp.next=n;
     temp=n;
     i++;
   }


}

// constructor -- initialize object with another StringLink    
public StringLink(StringLink other)
{
   Node temp=other.head;
   temp=temp.next;
   len=other.length();
   for (int i=0; i<this.len; i++)
   {
     Node n= new Node();
     n.c= temp.c;
     n.index=i+1;
     if (temp.next!=null){
       temp=temp.next;
       n.next=temp;
     }
     else n.next=null;

   }
}
```

And here is the toString() method that won't work:

```
 public String toString()
{
  char[] narr= new char[this.len];
  Node temp= new Node();
  temp=this.head;
  temp=temp.next;
  System.out.println(temp.c);
  for (int i=0; i<this.len;i++)
  {
    narr[i]=temp.c;
    System.out.println(narr[i]);
    if (temp.next!=null)
      temp=temp.next;

  }
  return new String(narr);




}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Which line is the NPE happening?

Comment: Holy pasta! Why all the stuff with char[] in toString()? Why not simply use StringBuilder?

Comment: @Plazsma, learn how to use `debugger`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second constructor, `this.head` is never initialized, so it is `null`. When you try to access it in `toString`, you have the NullPointerException.

Actually in the second constructor, you seem to build Node objects that you simply throw away, since you don't assign them to anything. You should really check your logic.